# How to get onclick item in an android recyclerview and send its attributes to a new activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I'm developing an android app for online order. User needs to click on an food item in recyclerView and I'm trying to send the food ID to the AddOrderActivity. How can I get the FId and pass it to the new activity?

CustomerHomeFragment.java

public class CustomerHomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FoodsAdapter adapter;
private List<Food> foodList;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_customer, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    Call<FoodsResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getFoods();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<FoodsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FoodsResponse> call, Response<FoodsResponse> response) {

            foodList = response.body().getFoods();
            adapter = new FoodsAdapter(getActivity(), foodList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FoodsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

public class FoodsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements View.OnClickListener{

```
private Context mCtx;
private List<Food> foodList;

public FoodsAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Food> foodList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.foodList = foodList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public FoodsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_foods, parent, false);
    return new FoodsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Food food = foodList.get(position);

    holder.textViewFName.setText(food.getFName());
    holder.textViewUnitPrice.setText(String.format("%d", food.getUnitPrice()));
    holder.textViewAvailCount.setText(String.format("%d", food.getAvailCount()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodList.size();
}


//////////////
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.mCtx, AddOrderActivity.class);
    this.mCtx.startActivity(intent);
}
/////////////////

class FoodsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewFName, textViewUnitPrice, textViewAvailCount;

    public FoodsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewFName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFName);
        textViewUnitPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUnitPrice);
        textViewAvailCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAvailCount);
    }
}
```

}

public class Food {

```
private int fid, unitprice, availcount;
private String fname;

public Food(int fid, String fname, int unitprice, int availcount) {
    this.fid = fid;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
    this.availcount = availcount;

}

public int getFId() {
    return fid;
}

public String getFName() {
    return fname;
}

public int getUnitPrice() {
    return unitprice;
}

public int getAvailCount() {
    return availcount;
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done some research?

Comment: I did some research and I just added "onClick(View view)" method to the "FoodsAdapter.java"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the your adapter class inside the onBindViewHolder function add this code

```
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(context,NoteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("note_id", currentNote.getNoteId());
                intent.putExtra("note_name",currentNote.getNoteName());
                intent.putExtra("note_teacher",currentNote.getNoteTeacher());
                intent.putExtra("note_university",currentNote.getNoteUniversity());
                intent.putExtra("note_image",currentNote.getNoteImage());
                intent.putExtra("note_is_downloaded", currentNote.getIsDownloaded());
                intent.putExtra("note_storage_path", currentNote.getStoragePath());
                intent.putExtra("note_download_link", currentNote.getNoteDownloadLink());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```